# Formik Field validate using Yup

Tags: reactjs, formik

I was looking at the [docs](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/field#validate), and you can validate a `Field` by passing `validate` to `Field` which is a function.

e.g.

```
const validate = value => {
  let errorMessage;
  if (!/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i.test(value)) {
    errorMessage = 'Invalid email address';
  }
  return errorMessage;
};

...

<Field validate={validate} name="email" type="email" />
```

How can I substitute the function `validate` to use `Yup` ?

## If you are going to ask why I'm doing this...

Instead of having a huge `validationSchema` object, I want to pass a `Yup` validation object directly to `Field` because my form is dynamic generated.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: Not sure why you were down voted, nothing wrong with the question. I'll upvote to compensate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like Formik doesn't provide a way to do this natively for some reason. You could do it like this:

```
<Field
  name="email"
  type="email"
  validate={value =>
    Yup.string()
      .matches(/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i, "Invalid")
      .validate(value)
      .then(() => undefined)
      .catch(({ errors }) => errors[0])
  }
/>
```

[Working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/58lw8786p) on CodeSandbox.